# Need help in splitting the address

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to split the below address into two lines:

```
ABCD E FGHI JKLMNOP QRSTU VWXYz Apt NUMBER1234 Block A
```

Characters 0-30 to line 1

Characters 31-end to the second line

If the 30th character is in between the word i want to push that whole word to the second line. In above address the 30th character is in between the the word "VWXYZ" so i want to move it to the line 2 like below.

The final results should be like this:

Line 1: ABCD E FGHI JKLMNOP QRSTU

Line 2: VWXYz Apt NUMBER1234 Block A

```
if(address.length > 30)                                                                                               
{
  string add = address.Tostring();
  string arraystring[] = add.split(" ");      
}
```

Comment: You can loop over the string checking the index of the space characters, once you reach an index above or equal 30 cut the rest of the string to a new line.

Comment: if the 30th character is in between the word i want to push whole word to second line. In above address the 30th character is in between the the word "VWXYZ" so i want to move it to the line 2 like below.Line 1: ABCD E FGHI JKLMNOP QRSTU

Line 2: VWXYz Apt NUMBER1234 Block A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes the assumption that anything over 30 goes to the next line. Even if it is 65 characters long. Check to make sure it is longer than 30, then check from 30 backward until you find the first space.

```
        string message = "ABCD E FGHI JKLMNOP QRSTU VWXYz Apt NUMBER1234 Block A";
        string firstline = message;
        string secondline="";
        if(message.Length > 30)
        {
            for(int i = 30; i > 0;)
            {
                if(message[i] == ' ')
                {
                    firstline = message.Substring(0, i);
                    secondline = message.Substring(i + 1);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what happens if the input is less than 30?

Comment: I would just move the firstline = message to the original declaration. Save you some lines

Comment: I went ahead and changed it. This way is technically faster, because it only has to change the value if it is longer than the first. I did it the other way originally due to an immediate reaction to your question

Comment: no worries. Your and my answer are very similar, but somehow i have three downvotes.. It doesn't make sense

Comment: I noticed, I was looking for a fundamental flaw in yours somewhere. Truthfully, I think yours is better, but not sure how to have the answer moved to you. I did up vote yours though

Answer (score -3):

Here is a very simple, extremely fast way to doing it without LINQ or Regex.

```
    public string[] SplitLine(string line, int numberOfCharacters)
    {
        if (line.Length < numberOfCharacters)
            return new [] { line }; // no splitting necessary

        string[] result = new string[2]; // only two lines needed

        int splitPoint = numberOfCharacters; // the position to split at if it is a white space

        // if it is not a white space, iterate the splitPoint down until you reach a white space character
        while (splitPoint >= 0 && line[splitPoint] != ' ')
            splitPoint--;

        //return the two lines
        result[0] = line.Substring(0, splitPoint);
        result[1] = line.Substring(splitPoint, line.Length - splitPoint);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: @L.B Don't follow, he wants to split a single input line

Comment: Sorry my bad, Suppose input is 100 chars and should be splitted to 4 lines.

Comment: Actually Moop is correct. It explicitly says that from 31 to end of line was the second string

Comment: @ezi Keep telling yourself that... Check out your perfect answer and how it doesn't always work: http://ideone.com/bD1usg

Comment: @Moop You still didn't post a case where it didn't work. Even in case without any spaces it worked well (while your code couldn't handle it).